# I have this countdown timer that I want running even after my activity closes

Tags: java, android

Here is my code,

```
             new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 forgotpass.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 forgotpass.setText("done!");
             }
          }.start();
```

I want it to continue to run even after my activity or application closes.

So far when i press the back button or the home button on the application it is running on it stops automatically and when i reopen the activity it starts back on 30. Is there any possible way I can have it continue to countdown even when the application or the activity is not running?

Comment: Then you should use AlarmManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) instead of CountDownTimer...

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way you can achieve that unless you do it in a Service.

Answer (score 0):

Start it as service. Bind the service in the `onDestroy()`